# Flutter - Page Transition Animation in NavBar (Need Help)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add a transition animation when navigating with my bottom navigation bar. Most of the guides use routes, and It didnt work for me. Here's how I implemented the navigation bar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color.fromRGBO(132, 159, 255, 1),
            Color.fromRGBO(255, 191, 112, 1),
          ],
        ),
        ),
        height: 80,
      ),
      NavigationBar(
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        onDestinationSelected: (int pnum2) {
          setState(() {
            pageindex = pnum2;
          });},
        selectedIndex: pageindex,
        destinations: const <Widget> [
            NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.newspaper_rounded),
              label: 'News'),
            NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school_rounded),
              label: 'Resources'),
            NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.support_agent_rounded),
              label: 'Support')],)],),
  body: <Widget> [ 
    Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                radius: 1.2,
                tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                focalRadius: 1,
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(255, 191, 112, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(132, 159, 255, 1)])),
            child: const NewsTextScreen()),
          const Resources_Section(),
          const SupportPage(),
        ][pageindex]
```

The app will navigate NewsTextScreen(),Resources_Section() and SupportPage(), these are classes not pages. How can I navigate with animation? Your help is apprecatiated!